# How to punctuate the phrase at end of this sentence - With arms crossed he looked as if to say is that all you have, big boy?

Tags: punctuation

How to punctuate the phrase at end of this sentence - With arms crossed he looked as if to say *is that all you have, big boy?*

Comment: *With arms crossed, he looked as if to say, "Is that all you have, big boy?"*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on English Language Learners.